# Problemas con función de cambio de mayúsculas/minúsculas

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, function

hice un código para cambiar mayúsculas por minúsculas y viceversa. Tengo un problema, el input:

```
input: hola como estan
```

pero el output:

```
output: HOLA COMo ESTAN
```

La o en "como" no se vio afectada por el código:

```
import re
def convert(w):
  return list(filter(None, re.split('\W+', w)))

def lol(w):
    a1 = (
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w",
     "x", "y", "z"])
    a2 = (
    ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
     "X", "Y", "Z"])
    w_list = list(map(str, w))
    w_listf = list(map(str, w))
    for i in w_list:
        if i in a1:
            index = a1.index(i)
            indexs = w_list.index(i)
            w_pos = a2[index]
            w_listf[indexs] = w_pos
        elif i in a2:
            index2 = a2.index(i)
            indexs2 = w_list.index(i)
            w_pos2 = a1[index2]
            w_listf[indexs2] = w_pos2
    r = str("".join(w_listf))
    return r

a = input()
ac = convert(a)

for i in ac:
  print(lol(i))
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! recorda tambien traducir el titulo!!!!

Comment: `str.index()` te da solo el índice de la primera aparición. Si la letra aparece varias veces, tu enfoque sólo cambia la primera. Por otro lado ¿es un ejercicio o es una necesidad real? Porque si es una necesidad, Python ya te lo da hecho: `a.upper()`

Comment: gracias!! Es un desafio... muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás usando una lista para comparar y otra lista para generar los cambios. Si una palabra contiene letras repetidas, `index = a1.index(i)` siempre va encontrar la primera coincidencia y no va a procesar las demás.

Para arreglar tu código yo propondría que la propia lista se vaya actualizando para que no volviera a tomar en cuenta esa letra:

```
def lol(w):
    a1 = (
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"])
    a2 = (
    ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"])
    w_list = list(map(str, w))
    for i in w_list:
        if i in a1:
            index = a1.index(i)
            indexs = w_list.index(i)
            w_pos = a2[index]
            w_list[indexs] = w_pos
        elif i in a2:
            index2 = a2.index(i)
            indexs2 = w_list.index(i)
            w_pos2 = a1[index2]
            w_list[indexs2] = w_pos2
    r = str("".join(w_list))
    return r
```

Como mencionaron, si es para cambiar de mayúsculas a minúsculas simplemente puedes usar las funciones de la librería estandar de python `str.upper()` y `str.lower()` y obviar todo ese código.

En caso de querer cambiar siempre una letra por la otra correspondiente, python posee métodos para "preguntar" si un string es mayúscula `str.isupper()` o minúscula `str.islower()`. Adicional, no necesitas convertir la cadena en lista para iterar sobre ella. Python puede iterar sobre una cadena directamente.

```
a = input()

new_str = ''
for lt in a:
    if lt.islower():
        new_str += lt.upper()
    elif lt.isupper():
        new_str += lt.lower()
    else:
        # numeros, espacios, otros caracteres
        new_str += lt
print(new_str)
```

> Entrada: `Hola Como eStas 234?`
>   Salida: `hOLA cOMO EsTAS 234?`

Comment: Gracias!!! Crack

Comment: Amigo ahora tengo un problema, cuando hay dos letras iguales seguidas, una en mayusculas y otra en minus, no funciona el codigo. Alguna idea de que esta ocurriendo???

Answer (score 1):

Como ya se ha explicado en la respuesta de @aeportugal y en los comentarios de @abulafia el problema es que `index` solo retorna el primer índice que encuentra. Siguiendo tu algoritmo, una solución mucho más simple es no usar `list.index` para buscar el carácter ne la lista , itera usando `enumerate` para obtener parejas `indice, carácter`:

```
def lol(w):
    a1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
          "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    a2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
          "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    w_list = list(map(str, w))
    for indexs, char in enumerate(w_list):
        if char in a1:
            index = a1.index(char)
            w_pos = a2[index]
            w_list[indexs] = w_pos
        elif char in a2:
            index = a2.index(char)
            w_pos = a1[index]
            w_list[indexs] = w_pos
    r = "".join(w_list)
    return r
```

Si quieres usar una aproximación "manual" si recurrir a `str.lower` y `str.upper` yo usaría diccionarios en vez de listas dado que las búsquedas son mucho más eficientes:

```
lowers_c = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzáéóúíü"
uppers_c = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚÜ"
chars = {l: u for l, u in zip(lowers_c + uppers_c, uppers_c + lowers_c)}

cadena = "Hola Cómo eStán"
invertido = "".join(chars.get(c, c) for c in cadena)
```

Quedaría añadir los caracteres acentuados al diccionario.
Una forma muy simple y eficiente usando `str.lower`, `str.upper` y `str.islower`/`isupper` es usando un generador y `str.join`:

```
cadena = "Hola Como eStán"
invertido = "".join(c.upper() if c.islower() else c.lower() for c in cadena)
```

> ```
> >>> invertido
> 'hOLA cÓMO EsTÁN'
> ```

Comment: Amigo ahora tengo un problema, cuando hay dos letras iguales seguidas, una en mayusculas y otra en minus, no funciona el codigo. Alguna idea de que esta ocurriendo???

Comment: Hola Felipe ¿Cómo tiene tu código ahora? En las soluciones que doy no hay problema con esto.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ruanmu si me queda y ocurre el error mencionado

Comment: el input: rR     el output: rR.... es igual

Comment: Según se ve en la imagen, no estas implementando las soluciones que te estamos dando @FelipeRiveraC.

Comment: Estoy usando la solucion de arriba... porque es solo cambiar una variable... al hacerlo se soluciona todo menos cuando hay dos letras iguales *una en mayus y otra en minus* donde no funciuona

Comment: @FelipeRiveraC. el problema es que si modificas la lista in-place la primera r pasa a R, cuando aplicas index de nuevo con la siguiente R retorna el índice de la antigua r (que ahora es R)... He añadido una solución basada en tu código que evita esto además de tu problema inicial.

Comment: no lo habia pensado asi!! muchas gracias